# Responsive two-line menu

Tags: html, css

I am trying to recreate the coding for this category menu: https://menu.thewhitebtq.com/collections/canapes

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

It is responsive. It's turning into a vertical 1 line when in mobile. I need to know the html and css for this.

This is my current HTML code:

```
&nbsp;
<div id="navigation">
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://goalexpo.com/canapes/">CANAPÉS</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://goalexpo.com/sandwicheswraps/">SANDWICHES &amp; WRAPS</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://goalexpo.com/fingerfood/">FINGER FOOD</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://goalexpo.com/mini-food-cups/">MINI CUPS</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- navigation -->
<div id="navigation">
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://goalexpo.com/mini-salads/">MINI SALADS</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://goalexpo.com/desserts/">DESSERTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://goalexpo.com/cakes-towers/">CAKES &amp; TOWERS</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://goenter code herealexpo.com/hot-cold-beverages/">HOT &amp; COLD BEVERAGES</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- navigation -->
```

Comment: use 'bootstrap' or 'wordpress' for better responsivity

Answer (score 0):

add **@media** query to adjust Your images on mobile and desktop windows.

```css
html,body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  }
img{
  width:30%;
  height:20%;
  }
@media screen and (max-width:768px){
  img{
    width:80%;
    height:20%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZCHl.jpg">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufSnP.jpg">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgKyr.jpg">
</div>
```

(in the above example if you **click on expand snippet** You can see the view on desktop view and on this snippet You can see the mobile window effect).

Comment: Hi, did you see the link? The catergories Canapes, Sandwiches and Wraps.... I want exactly the same. How can I do the css for this?

Comment: @jules you can use this idea to create that one also

Comment: Hi White Maskers,